# psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "dev"

Tags: postgresql

when i create a new user, but it cannot login the database.
I do that like this:

```
postgres@Aspire:/home/XXX$ createuser dev
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) n
Shall the new role be allowed to create databases? (y/n) y
Shall the new role be allowed to create more new roles? (y/n) y
```

then create a database:

```
postgres@Aspire:/home/XXX$ createdb -O dev test_development
```

after that, I try `psql -U dev -W test_development` to login, but get the error:

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "dev"
```

I tried to solve the problem but failed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PG Peer authentication failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306770/pg-peer-authentication-failed)

Comment: now, to be prompted for answers to the above questions you need to add `--interactive` to the command: `createuser --interactive joe`

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Try:

```
psql -U user_name  -h 127.0.0.1 -d db_name
```

where

- `-U` is the database user name
- `-h` is the hostname/IP of the local server, thus avoiding Unix domain sockets
- `-d` is the database name to connect to

This is then evaluated as a "network" connection by Postgresql rather than a Unix domain socket connection, thus not evaluated as a "local" connect as you might see in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

Comment: I needed (ver 9.4): psql -U user-name -h 127.0.0.1 -d db-name

Comment: what an ornery tool. the manual says `psql [option...] [dbname [username]]`, so you'd think `psql dbname username` would just work..

Comment: Worked for me as well. I also think this is a much more preferable way than changing config files, especially when you don't have a clue about what you are doing and just following SO answer to solve your problem.

Comment: this worked for me, thanks a lot, though I am doing a research as to why it was the correct solution. nevertheless, in a configuration in another machine I would login as psql -U username -d database . so i guess that the accepted solution depends on the case.

Comment: Good answer. I was getting from inside the database after having logged in as postgres

`\c glossary john`

`FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "john"`
then with
`\c glossary john localhost`
`Password for user john:`
`SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)`
`You are now connected to database "glossary" as user "john" on host "localhost" at port "5432".`
it worked.

Comment: Why is the `-h` required? I have Postgres databases that require it and ones that don't. What's the difference?

Answer (score 238):

Your connection failed because by default `psql` connects over UNIX sockets using `peer` authentication, that requires the current UNIX user to have the same user name as `psql`. So you will have to create the UNIX user `dev` and then login as `dev` or use `sudo -u dev psql test_development` for accessing the database (and `psql` should **not** ask for a password).

If you cannot or do not want to create the UNIX user, like if you just want to connect to your database for *ad hoc* queries, forcing a socket connection using `psql --host=localhost --dbname=test_development --username=dev` (as pointed out by @meyerson answer) will solve your immediate problem.

But if you intend to force password authentication over Unix sockets instead of the peer method, try changing the following `pg_hba.conf`* line:

from

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD
local  all      all          peer
```

to

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD
local  all      all          md5
```

- `peer` means it will trust the identity (authenticity) of UNIX user. So not asking for a password.
- `md5` means it will always ask for a password, and validate it after hashing with `MD5`.

You can, of course, also create more specific rules for a specific database or user, with some users having `peer` and others requiring passwords.

After changing `pg_hba.conf` if PostgreSQL is running you'll need to make it re-read the configuration by reloading (`pg_ctl reload`) or restarting (`sudo service postgresql restart`).

<sup>* The file `pg_hba.conf` will most likely be at `/etc/postgresql/9.x/main/pg_hba.conf`</sup>

**Edited:** *Remarks from @Chloe, @JavierEH, @Jonas Eicher, @fccoelho, @Joanis, @Uphill_What comments incorporated into answer.*

Comment: How do you allow `peer` *AND* `md5`? When I set `md5`, then I can no longer login with `postgres` user! I tried adding multiple lines, and separating the method with commas, but they didn't work. Ok I found `mgoldwasser`'s answer and that worked. I just added another line for user `postgres` with method `peer`!

Comment: Dont worry, you can set peer authentication for specific users (for example, your username or postgres). It seems that specific rules override general rules

Comment: On some distributions the file might also be found here: ``/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf``

Comment: can't you do this without restarting postgresql? can't you just specify the authentication method in the pg_user table?

Comment: You can reload instead of restart. That reloads the pg_hba table. Worked for me.

Answer (score 30):

Peer authentication means that postgres asks the operating system for your login name and uses this for authentication. To login as user "dev" using peer authentication on postgres, you must also be the user "dev" on the operating system.

You can find details to the authentication methods in the [Postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/auth-methods.html).

**Hint:** If no authentication method works anymore, disconnect the server from the network and use method "trust" for "localhost" (and double check that your server is not reachable through the network while method "trust" is enabled).

Comment: thanks for your answers.but it still don't work if i change the `dev` to system user `XXX`

Comment: stefan's answer is correct.  I just added a link, which will be visible when my edit is reviewed, to the documentation where each of the authentication methods are explained.

Answer (score 25):

When you specify:

```
psql -U user
```

it connects via UNIX Socket, which by default uses `peer` authentication, unless specified in `pg_hba.conf` otherwise.

You can specify:

```
host    database             user             127.0.0.1/32       md5
host    database             user             ::1/128            md5
```

to get TCP/IP connection on loopback interface (both IPv4 and IPv6) for specified `database` and `user`.

After changes you have to restart postgres or reload it's configuration.
Restart that should work in modern RHEL/Debian based distros:

```
service postgresql restart
```

Reload should work in following way:

```
pg_ctl reload
```

but the command may differ depending of PATH configuration - you may have to specify absolute path, which may be different, depending on way the postgres was installed.

Then you can use:

```
psql -h localhost -U user -d database
```

to login with that `user` to specified `database` over TCP/IP.
`md5` stands for encrypted password, while you can also specify `password` for plain text passwords during authorisation. These 2 options shouldn't be of a great matter as long as database server is only locally accessible, with no network access.

**Important note:**
Definition order in `pg_hba.conf` matters - rules are read from top to bottom, like iptables, so you probably want to add proposed rules above the rule:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
```

Comment: re the Important note: - order is important +1

Answer (score 24):

While @flaviodesousa's answer would work, it also makes it mandatory for all users (everyone else) to enter a password.

Sometime it makes sense to keep peer authentication for everyone else, but make an exception for a service user. In that case you would want to add a line to the pg_hba.conf that looks like:

```
local   all             some_batch_user                         md5
```

I would recommend that you add this line right below the commented header line:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             some_batch_user                         md5
```

You will need to restart PostgreSQL using

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

If you're using 9.3, your pg_hba.conf would most likely be:

> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

Answer (score 13):

This works for me when I run into it:

```
sudo -u username psql
```

Comment: only works if you create a whole new user on the system AND in postgres -- hsming just wants to connect to postgres with the newly created postgres user, `dev`.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest solution:

```
CREATE USER dev WITH PASSWORD 'dev';
CREATE DATABASE test_development;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test_development to dev;
ALTER ROLE dev CREATEROLE CREATEDB;
```

Answer (score 9):

I simply had to add `-h localhost`

Comment: My issue was using postgres on a Raspberry. ^^^ worked for me!!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using different port. Default is 5432. I was using 5433. This worked for me:

```
$ psql -f update_table.sql -d db_name -U db_user_name -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433
```

Comment: This can occure automatically when you have more than one installation of postgres.

Answer (score 1):

For people in the future seeing this, `postgres` is in the `/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin` on my Ubuntu server.

I added it to the PATH in my .bashrc file, and add this line at the end

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin
```

then on the command line

```
$> source ./.bashrc
```

I refreshed my bash environment. Now I can use `postgres -D /wherever` from any directory

Answer (score 1):

pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres -F c -b -v -f mydb.backup mydb

Comment: What question does this answer? Why might `-U postgres` be pivotal? What are all those *dash-letters*, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Try in terminal:

```
>> psql -U role_name -d database -h hostname.<domain>.com -W
```

Comment: Please add a little more context to you answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter the error: `psql: error: FATAL: Peer authentication failed` for user "dev”, you will need to allow the new SQL user to be authenticated.

Add Client Authentication to new user for PostgreSQL:

To add the Client Authentication for a new user in SQL and allow it to authenticate, the steps are the following:

- Edit the Client authentication file named pg_hba.conf this can generally be done with the command (in this case, I use PostgreSQL version 12): `sudo nano /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf`
- Add a line toward the bottom of the file, following the previous lines spacing with the following content:

  local   all             dev                                 md5
- Save the file. Then restart PostgreSQL with: `sudo service postgresql restart`

You should now be able to connect to your new user with psql -U dev.
If you want help with the whole process of creating a PostgreSQL user and setting it up (as well as a new database) I have written a whole tutorial on it at: https://medium.com/p/44a38362bad9