# Postgres Rails (linux) troubleshooting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano3

Sorry if this question is a little fuzzy, but I am struggling to get my Rails app and postgres database connected on an Amazon Linux setup.

I have used https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-postgresql to set up the database after installing the DB.

I'm on Amazon Linux, have setup postgres only with this plugin after running `yum install postgresql94 postgresql94-devel postgresql94-server postgresql94-contrib`)

I am currently seeing this error message when my Rails project tries to connect to postgres

```
DEBUG [4f02c446]    Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
DEBUG [4f02c446]    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deployer@testproject: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "testuser_staging"
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:916:in `initialize'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `new'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/var/www/testproject/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I am noticing the message **`PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "testuser_staging"`**

This tells me that the server actually responds but here ** I need some advice for testing my configuration **

### Troubleshooting attempt #1: hba_conf

I have looked at my `hba_conf` and attempted to create a line for the `testuser_staging` user:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   testproject_staging    testuser_staging                           password
```

I tried putting both `password` and `md5` here, but got the same error message that `Ident authentication failed`.

I also tried changing to the default `peer` which did not work. That gave another error message ('peer authentication failed'), which I understand, since `testuser_staging` of course isnt a unix user.

### Troubleshooting attempt #2: rails database console

Now, my attempt to connect above was by running `cap staging rails:rake:db:migrate`. Could running via capistrano be flawed?. To error that out I logged into the server. It gave the same error message if I navigate to `/var/www/testproject/current` and run `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rails dbconsole`.

### Troubleshooting attempt #3: psql console

On the other hand, on the server I can get a 'password' error by running:

```
$ psql -U testuser_staging -d testproject 
Password for user testuser_staging: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "testuser_staging"
```

This seems odd to me. I am getting different error messages from command line postgres and from rails dbconsole.

File contents of `database.yml`:

```
staging:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: testproject_staging
  pool: 5
  username: testuser_staging
  password: 'the_test_pw'
  host: localhost
```

Contents of `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
    # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
local   testproject_staging    testuser_staging                           password
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

note the first line, `trust`, which I added to provoke locally connection possibilities. That actually works, but not from within Rails.

## Question time:

- What can I do to pinpoint my errors here?
- Any trouble-shooting tips to share?
- Any server setup which are prerequisite prior to using this plugin?**

I am aware of other answers explaining how to setup `pg_hba.conf`: [psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "dev"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443379/psql-fatal-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-dev). Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Please show the **complete** contents of `pg_hba.conf`

Comment: Need to see your database.yml (mask the passwords) as well.