# PostgreSQL 9.6 server showing down after starting in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu

I am trying to install and use PostgreSQL in ubuntu 14.04. I followed these commands to reinstall postgresql.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*
sudo rm -r /etc/postgresql/
sudo rm -r /etc/postgresql-common/
sudo rm -r /var/lib/postgresql/
sudo userdel -r postgres
sudo groupdel postgres
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
sudo -i -u postgres 
postgres@user:~$ psql
```

Here the error comes,

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>           Is the server running locally and accepting
>           connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

When I check `sudo service postgresql status`, it returns

```
9.6/main (port 5432): down
```

Then I run the command `sudo service postgresql start`, it returns

```
* Starting PostgreSQL 9.6 database server
```

Again,

user@user:~$ `sudo service postgresql status`

```
9.6/main (port 5432): down
```

I don't know why? Someone please help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have another doubt, In postgresql, Is it not possible to create database or user other than the name of my linux account? I can create it in postgresql CLI, But I could not use it in my Rails application. It is throwing the error.

`PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "jayam"`

Comment: Read about pg_hba.conf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PG Peer authentication failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306770/pg-peer-authentication-failed)