# run psql on postgres dockerfile

Tags: postgresql, dockerfile, psql

From a postgres standard images I install postgis and after I should run psql command to CREATE EXTENSION POSTGIS. I think that my problem is to set the correct -h parameter in the psql command but I'm not sure about it. Any idea?

```html
FROM postgres:12.1

MAINTAINER xxx

#ARG A_DB_USER='postgres'
#ARG A_DB_PASS='postgres'
ARG A_DB_NAME='postgres'
ARG A_TZ='Europe/Zurich'

#ENV DB_USER=${A_DB_USER}
#ENV DB_PASS=${A_DB_PASS}
ENV DB_NAME=${A_DB_NAME}
ENV TZ=${A_TZ}

# Adjusting Timezone in the system
RUN echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata && \
    rm /etc/localtime && \
    ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && \
    dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata && \
    apt-get clean

# install postgis
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y postgis && \
    apt-get clean

USER postgres

#Add password "postgres" to user postgres, create db, add .sql
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start && psql -U postgres -d mydb -h localhost -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"


EXPOSE 5432
```

The error is: `psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
ERROR: Service 'istsos-db' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /etc/init.d/postgresql start && psql -U postgres -d istsos -h localhost -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"' returned a non-zero code: 2`

EDIT:
I run it with a docker-compose

```html
version: '3.7'

services:

  app-db:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-pg
    image: app-pg:1.0.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: app
      POSTGRES_DB: app-db
    volumes:
       - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sh
       - v-app-pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql
       - v-app-pglog:/data/var/log/postgresql
       - v-app-pgconf:/etc/postgresql


    
  app-main:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-tar-cp
    image: app-main:1.0.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
volumes:
  v-app-pgdata:
    name: v-app-pgdata
  v-app-pglog:
    name: v-app-pglog
  v-app-pgconf:
    name: v-app-pgconf
```

I tried to use `POSTGRES_DB: app-db` and to specify `psql -h app-db`
But docker-build returns:
`No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster" ... (warning).
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not translate host name "app-db" to address: Name or service not known
ERROR: Service 'app-db' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /etc/init.d/postgresql start && psql -U postgres -d app -h app-db -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"' returned a non-zero code: 2`

I also try with localhost without success.
Any ideas?

Comment: take a look at this, looks like it's the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637206/is-the-server-running-on-host-localhost-1-and-accepting-tcp-ip-connections

Comment: @cogitoergosum I tried to specify `POSTGRES_DB: app-db` in docker-compose and use `psql -h app-db` without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code for your run script.

```
RUN    /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

EDIT:

Please add the below to make sure ports are open and pg listen to external IP's as well.

```
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /folder/to/conf/pg_hba.conf
```

**add listen to all ip's**

```
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /folder/to/conf/postgresql.conf
```

Comment: it returns: psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
ERROR: Service 'app-db' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&    psql --command "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"' returned a non-zero code: 2

Comment: can you add listen all address and remote connections as well to check:

RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /folder/to/conf/pg_hba.conf

add listen to all ip's

RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /folder/to/conf/postgresql.conf