# docker-compose services.db.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object. Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy

I am building a Flask application in Python. I'm using SQLAlchemy to connect to PostgreSQL.

I used this to successfully connect my SQLALchemy in the flask app to my postgresql.

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:[mypassword]@localhost:5432/employee-manager-db')
```

However, I run into an error when I try to do docker-compose up.
This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app

    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:14.5
    restart: always
    expose:
      - '5432'
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - 'db:5432'
```

I don't know why it is not recognizing db as an object.

Edit: I had the same problem as this ([Docker: Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637206/docker-is-the-server-running-on-host-localhost-1-and-accepting-tcp-ip-con)) and tried to fix it, but I am currently facing this error instead.
Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ports` option for a service is a list of `<host_port>:<container_port>` mappings. Both the `<host_port>` and `<container_port>` parts need to be integers, which `db` is not.

You probably want:

```
  db:
    image: postgres:14.5
    restart: always
    expose:
      - '5432'
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
```

Comment: When I do that, I get an error saying "Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Address not available. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8). employee-manager_backend_1 exited with code 1. employee-manager_db_1 exited with code 0 "

Comment: @NendoRiki  So your original problem is solved.  now you have a different problem, and question.

Comment: I think this answer accurately identifies the problem in your question. If you have a follow-up, mark this as accepted and open a new question.

Comment: Ok I will just accept this one. But as I showed in the edit, the answer just took me back to the original problem