# Specifying ports inside docker-compose.yml for using postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy

I am building a Flask application in Python. I'm using SQLAlchemy to connect to PostgreSQL.

I used this to successfully connect my SQLALchemy in the flask app to my postgresql.

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:[mypassword]@localhost:5432/employee-manager-db')
```

I am get an error when I do docker-compose up.
This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app

    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:14.5
    restart: always
    expose:
      - '5432'
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
```

I read the post [Docker: Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637206/docker-is-the-server-running-on-host-localhost-1-and-accepting-tcp-ip-con) and noted that I have to change my connection details in the config to connect to db:5432, but I am struggling to figure out how to do it. Where do I change the config?

Thank you so much for help.

Comment: you need to change the line that you posted: `engine = create_engine......`. Replace `localhost` with `db`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes have to be made in your code not in the compose file, specifically

Change

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:[mypassword]@localhost:5432/employee-manager-db')
```

To

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:[mypassword]@db:5432/employee-manager-db')
```

The container is discoverable through its service name, in your case `db`.

In the first case you provided `localhost` instead, this would work if you didnt work with containers

But now your application lives in containers not in your host, so you need to change the address in order for the `backend` service to reach your `db` service

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved the original problem. However, I now get "Is the server running on host "db" (172.20.0.2) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?", which is similar but "localhost" replaced with "db". Does this indicate that the server is not running on host "db"? Sorry I only studied software engineering for like a month and no idea what's happening

Comment: For this it seems there is an issue with your db container. Create a new question with its log output and I would be glad to assist you further :)