# getting error PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "job_portal"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, capistrano, psql, capistrano3

So i've been trying to deploy my app to production using capistrano, but getting this error. i have changed my postgres configuration from peer to md5. i manually created the db job_portal production in psql and added the details to database.yml file. i have tried many things but nothing seems to work, could i get some help?

database.yml 
   
`test:
  <<: *default
  database: job_portal_test
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: elrich_3
  password: 12345
production:
  <<: *default
  database: job_portal_production
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: elr_4
  password: 12345`

pg_hba.conf

`

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

`
[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAJVa.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL: FATAL - Peer authentication failed for user (PG::ConnectionBad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306770/postgresql-fatal-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-pgconnectionbad)

Comment: yes i restarted the server @jjanes

Comment: it works when i run psql -d <dbname> -U <username> -h <hostname> in psql, but get erroe while deploying @SeoungHoJeoung

Comment: peer authentication is only possible over unix-domain sockets ("local" lines from pg_hba), while `host: localhost` should not be using those.  I don't see how to explain this, other than that your `database.yml` you show is not the one being used.

Comment: I'm not getting how is it not selecting the db i have specified in database.yml file @jjanes